# Quick and easy way to check if all items in a dictionary are empty strings?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of N items. Their values are strings, but I'm looking for an easy way to detect if they are all empty strings.

```
{'a': u'', 'b': u'', 'c': u''}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
not any(dict.itervalues())
```

Or:

```
all(not X for X in dict.itervalues())
```

Whichever you find clearer.

Comment: Or, if you really want to check for empty strings instead of falsy truth values, `all(x == "" for x in my_dict.itervalues())`.

Comment: Yeah, your list comprehension is probably better than my proposal.

Comment: @Ishpeck: No list comprehensions here, only generator expressions.

Comment: Cool beans, I'm pretty new to python do I didn't know about all or any!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> d={'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':''}
>>> any(map(bool, d.values()))
False
>>> d={'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':'oaeu'}
>>> any(map(bool, d.values()))
True
```

Comment: The `map(bool,...)` part is redundant -- `any()` will convert to `bool` anyway.  This is a bit like `if a == True`.